# format RTL text and column in console C#

Tags: c#, right-to-left, string.format, console.writeline

I'm using 'string.Format' to manipulate text and creating columns

```
    string.Format("{0, -4}{1, -16}{2, 11}\n", "#", "Name", "Price")
```

and result in English and LTR format is correct:

```
    ‎#   Name                  Price
    --- -------            --------
    1   Product1             234440
    2   Product2              34455
```

when I change languages and use arabic characters, the columns alignment display is not correct:

```
    ‎#     نام               قیمت
    --- -------            --------
    1   محصول ۲            ۳۴۲۳۴
    2   محصول ۳            ۴۵۳۴۵۳
```

I use \u200E and \u200F also, but result did not changes.

my desired column display is:

```
    نام                  قیمت   #
    -----              ------- ---
    محصول۱              ۱۲۲۲۳   #
    محصول۲               ۲۲۳۳   #
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code sample. Second series that are based on `baseStr2` works as you desired.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var baseStr = "{0, -4}{1, -16}{2, 11}\n";

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(baseStr, "#", "Name", "Price"));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(baseStr, "#", "Product1", "1232132"));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(baseStr, "#", "P 2", "88"));
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(baseStr, "#", "نام", "قیمت"));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(baseStr, "#", "فرش", "1232132"));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(baseStr, "#", "یخچال فریزر", "88"));

    Console.WriteLine("------------------------");

    var baseStr2 = "{2, -11}{1, 16}{0, 14}\n";

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(baseStr2, "#", "Name", "Price"));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(baseStr2, "#", "Product1", "1232132"));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(baseStr2, "#", "P 2", "88"));
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(baseStr2, "#", "نام", "قیمت"));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(baseStr2, "۳۴۲۳۴", "فرش", "1232132"));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(baseStr2, "۴۵۳۴۵۳", "یخچال فریزر", "88"));

    Console.WriteLine("------------------------");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
but, when I use number instead of "#", the columns does not display properly!

Comment: you can test it in Debug mode to see Persian characters!

Comment: Just edited my answer. I increase 4 to 14 in `baseStr2`

Comment: Agree, cmd and terminal does not support RTL natively.